# Yii2 Kartik GridView Export redirecting to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, gridview, yii2, export

I am using a Yii2 Kartik GridView extension and trying to make an html and excel exportation. When I click export and choose type of file. I'm getting the popup that said that I can close the window after download.
When trying to trigger the Download action, I have a 302 Found HTTP response from server and it redirects to the homepage without downloading my file.

I was thinking that this due to the force using https in my htaccess. But when I tried to disable the SSL certificate, still doesn't work.

The only way that it works, is when I put off mod_security in the server!

Here is my Grid view code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'export' => true,
'toolbar'=> ['{export}', '{toggleData}'],
'panel' => [
    'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i> Samir</h3>',
    'type'=>'success',
],
'exportConfig' => [
    \kartik\grid\GridView::HTML => [
        'label' => 'HTML',
        'filename' => 'myhtml',
    ],
    \kartik\grid\GridView::EXCEL => [
        'label' => 'Excel',
        'filename' => 'myexcel',
    ],
],
'columns' => $myColumns,]); ?>
```

And here is my .htaccess file:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.phpe
```

All my extensions are up to date.
Anyone can help please?

Comment: Interesting case... Never had a problem with server configuration. Perhaps ask Yii2 developers themselves. :)

Comment: I've already asked the developper of the GridView widget and I hope to have some clarification or leads to follow.